# TensorFlow: simple recurrent neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I've built some neural networks with TensorFlow, like basic MLPs and convolutional neural networks. Now I want to move on to recurrent neural networks. However, I'm not experienced in natural language processing. Therefore the TensorFlow NLP tutorials for RNNs are not easy to read for me (and not really interesting, too).

Basically I want to start off with something simple, not a LSTM.

**How would one build a simple recurrent neural network, like an Elman network, in TensorFlow?**

I were only able to find GRU- or LSTM RNN examples for TensorFlow, mostly for NLP. Does anyone know of some simple recurrent neural network tutorials or examples for TensorFlow?

This figure shows a basic Elman network, which is often simply called SRN (simple recurrent network):

[image: elman network example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the built-in RNNCell located in [tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/16d395e5dea687ab3aece0a462e631de25c8d77d/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py).

If you don't want to do that you can make your own RNN. The RNN will train using back-propagation through time. Try unrolling the network a fixed number of steps, e.g. consider input sequences of length ten. Then you can write a loop in python to do all of the matrix multiplications for each step of the network. Each time you can take the output from the previous step and concatenate it with the input to that step. It will not be too many lines of code to get this working.

Comment: I've tried to built something with the RNN Cell but I weren't really successful. I always end up with `raise TypeError("inputs must be a list")` or `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` when I either supply a numpy array or a list. Additionally, what exactly is the `state` for? I thought it is the most recent vector out of the context layer, but why would this need an explicit `2D Tensor with shape [batch_size x self.state_size]` then (according to the docs)? Could you supply an example?

Comment: Yeah the state is the most recent context vector. Usually you process multiple sequences together in a batch. So the 2d tensor is the state vectors from each of the sequences in the batch.

Comment: https://github.com/rajarsheem/playing-with-RNNs/blob/master/int_seq.ipynb
Have a look at this. If you need explanation, create an issue there.